# How to prevent download notification from disappearing in Android API 10

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-2.3-gingerbread, download-manager

I am using download manager to download some files into the app. It works fine for API level > 10 but the notification comes and goes for API 10. I have to implement it on API 10 so please dont ask me to change the MinSdkVersion. The code for the download manager is as follows.

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Uri uri = Uri
                .parse(serverConnection.url + serverConnection.studentSearchService + "GetAssignmentFile/" + serverConnection.connectionString + fileList.get(i).getFileId());



        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request downloadReq = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        downloadReq
                .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                        | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
      //  downloadReq.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        downloadReq.setMimeType(fileList.get(i).getFileType());
        downloadReq.setTitle(fileList.get(i).getFileName());
        NotificationView.fileTypeToOpen=fileList.get(i).getFileType();
        NotificationView.fileToOpen=fileList.get(i).getFileName();
        downloadReq.setDescription("attachment");
        downloadReq.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileList.get(i).getFileName());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

             downloadReq.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE | DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        }
        else
        {
            downloadReq.setShowRunningNotification(true);
        }


        long enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(downloadReq);

    }
}
```

I also tried using a broadcast receiver but am unable to handle the onclick event of the notification.

Broadcast Receiver

> public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>       @Override
>       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>           String action = intent.getAction();
>
> ```
>     if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
>         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
>             }
>         else
>         {
>             Notification(context,"Downloaded");
>
>         }
> ```
>
> Toast.makeText(context,"Download
>   Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
>
> ```
>     if(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action))
>     {
>         Toast.makeText(context,"Notification Cliekd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
>
> }
> public void Notification(Context context, String message) {
>     // Set Notification Title
>     String strtitle = "Attachment Download Complete";
>     // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
>     Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
>     // Send data to NotificationView Class
>     intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
>     intent.putExtra("text", message);
>     // Open NotificationView.java Activity
>     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
>             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
>     // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
>     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
>             context)
>             // Set Icon
>             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_attachment)
>                     // Set Ticker Message
>             .setTicker(message)
>                     // Set Title
>             .setContentTitle("Attachment")
>                     // Set Text
>             .setContentText(message)
>                     // Add an Action Button below Notification
>             .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_attachment, "Action Button", pIntent)
>                     // Set PendingIntent into Notification
>             .setContentIntent(pIntent)
>                     // Dismiss Notification
>             .setAutoCancel(true);
>
>     // Create Notification Manager
>     NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
>             .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>     // Build Notification with Notification Manager
>     notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

the Download complete event is triggered, but the notification clicked is not. I have registered the receivers in the manifest.

```
   <receiver android:name="appPath.DownloadBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFICATION_CLICKED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Weird enough, I tried your example and it works perfectly on 5.0, without listening to the broadcasts o.O